# WITH statement does not persist outside of query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, cte

I run a select to check what records I should register in another table.

Each record returned in the query I should give an insert in my table `campanha_cliente_chamada`.

```
WITH psql as ( /* stuff */ )    
SELECT * FROM psql; 

WITH disca ( /* reads from psql */ )  
INSERT INTO callcenter.campanha_cliente_chamada ( columns )
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM   disca;
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Error : relation psql does not exist LINE 11: ( SELECT
id_camapanha_cliente FROM psql),(SELECT c...
                          ^
```

Comment: Either chain your CTEs in one statement, or use views. CTEs are only defined within one statement. If you want it to be available in another statement, create a view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually chain CTEs:

```
WITH psql as ( /* stuff */ ),    
disca as ( SELECT * FROM psql )  
INSERT INTO callcenter.campanha_cliente_chamada ( columns )
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM   disca;
```

... which may help you.

Comment: This isn't what he's asking about. He knows he can chain CTEs. He's trying to use a CTE defined in a prior statement.

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Table Expressions (CTE)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) vs VIEW

A [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) is a materialized alias, that functions in the context of the statement it's defined in.

```
WITH foo AS (
  VALUES (1)
)
SELECT * FROM foo; -- works

SELECT * FROM foo; -- does not persist after statement termination
                   -- or outside the statement
```

Gets planned and executed, `foo` is aliased to the result set of the above and for the query you can reference `VALUES (1)` as `foo`, but after that query that named alias is lost.

What you may want is a [`TEMPORARY VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html) instead.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW foo
AS
  VALUES (1);
SELECT * FROM foo; -- works here.

SELECT * FROM foo; -- and works here.
```

If you want that `VIEW` to be visible across different sessions and persist through session termination, remove `TEMPORARY` and use [`CREATE VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html)

Also calling a CTE psql is horrible practice. `psql` is the name of the PostgreSQL client.